# Longest path through graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with 80k nodes and 180k vertices for which I want to compute the top-5 longest paths (based on a property) from start to finish. I'm using Neo4j 4.3 community edition.

I have the following Cypher query but it is excruciatingly slow:

```
MATCH p = (a:Start)-[:FLOWS_TO*]->(b:Finish)
RETURN
  length(p)                                       AS steps
, reduce(sum=0, n in nodes(p) | sum + n.cost)     AS total_cost
ORDER BY
  total_cost DESC
LIMIT 5
```

All intermediate nodes have the same label. If I run `EXPLAIN` for the query, i see an intermediate step with 425 billion rows, which is why it's so slow. Unfortunately, I have no idea how long the most expensive path is, so I cannot limit `FLOWS_TO:1..X` with X some integer.

There are no cycles in the graph.

Is there a way to speed up the query or solve the problem in a better way?

Comment: Are you sure there is not some upper limit on X?
Alternatively, you could move away from a linked list and model it differently so that this query becomes easier (e.g. a "Path" node directly connected to each of the steps, with an order attribute on each of them).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the suggestion.

Comment: I don't know your domain, but instead of having `(:Step)-[:FLOWS_TO]->(:Step)-[:FLOWS_TO]-(:Step)-...->(:Step)`, you could have something like: `(p:Path)<-[FLOWS {order:0}]-(:Step), (p)<-[FLOWS {order:1}]-(:Step), ..., (p)<-[FLOWS {order:n}]-(:Step)`

Comment: And (p:Path) would already be an aggregate of sub-paths?

Comment: Something like that. Feel free to change the label names to something better of course. But such a model would make your "top 5 longest path" query much easier (just order by `:FLOWS{order} DESC`, pick the 5 first and return the required information).

Comment: Just means I have to pre-aggregate a lot of stuff, which kind of defeats the purpose of using a graph in the first place.

Comment: One option would be to pick some nodes with high costs (as they are most likely to be included in the most expensive paths anyway). Is there a smart way to specify a list of nodes that have to be somewhere in the path?

Comment: I can add it into the path in `MATCH` but I'm not sure that's the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to share much more details about your model and the queries you want to run. https://community.neo4j.com/ is likely a better place for that.